# Valid zip file in python

Tags: python, zip

I uploaded zip folder using file input,but when i check if this zip is valid or not;the result was:is not a valid pkzip file,i don't know what is the specification for valid pkzip.
I used this code to check:

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 
file_upload = form['file[]']
if zipfile.is_zipfile(file_upload.filename):
    print "%s is a valid pkzip file" % file_upload.filename
else:
    print "%s is not a valid pkzip file" % file_upload.filename
```

I don't know why?for example when i upload test.zip,the o/p will be:
test.zip is not a valid pkzip file,I need a help.Thanks

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`zipfile.is_zipfile` takes a path to a file or a file-like object. You're passing it neither, so it fails.

Ask it about `file_upload.file` instead.

Comment: :i used python 2.5 and work on eclipse ,i tried as you say;file_upload.file,but the error is : coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, cStringIO.StringO found.What is the problem,please?

Comment: You'll need to read the file -- it might be `.getvalue()`; I can't remember the exact method -- and pass the data to `zipfile`. Or else write it to a `TemporaryFile`.

Comment: @ katrielalex:how can i get the path of uploaded file to use it in:zipfile.is_zipfile???Thanks

Comment: @Eng_Engineer No, you haven't understood. The uploaded file _doesn't have a path_. It's in memory. You can either a) write it to disk somewhere, thus giving it a path (the `tempfile` module will automatically choose somewhere arbitrary to put it) or b) just pass the object directly.

Comment: @Eng_Engineer What you're asking is: `is "foo.zip" a valid zipfile?`. Obviously that doesn't make sense! `foo.zip` is a __name__. Names aren't zipfiles.